# Avoid Google Hangout notifications on phone while chatting on laptop

Tags: notifications, audio, google-hangouts

Hangout notifications on my phone are fine when someone starts up a conversation with me. But once I start chatting to them on the computer, I still get a (loud) notification tone on my phone every time they say anything if I'm in another window.

Any way to avoid this?

Comment: Interesting. Even I use Hangouts like you do, but once I start using computer, no notifications are shown on phone. I haven't changed any setting for this.

Comment: Put your phone on silent?

Comment: Heh. I guess...

Comment: I have the same issue and if i silence hangouts notifications on mobile they get silenced also on pc